# group DataFrame and increment group id if the number of rows have 3 consecutives same value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
max_skip=2
data = {'col1':['NT', 'NT', 'NT', 'T','T','T','NT', 'NT', 'T','T','T','NT', 'NT', 'NT',"T",'T','T','T','NT','NT']}
 
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
```

[image] 

I would like to group those data with the following rule:

1. If the number of consecutive NT is more than max_skip, assign those rows to group 0 else assign those rows to the current group id (group id starts from 0)
2. The next row will have its group id incremented if the previous row contains more than 2 (max_skip) consecutive NT, otherwise, the group id will still be the same.

which need to give me the following result. But how could I achieve this with any available built-in function without having to loop each of the rows?

```
df['group']=[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be done with one line, but it works.

```
df['lenghts'] = df.groupby(((df.col1 != df.col1.shift())).cumsum()).transform('size')
df['group']=df.groupby(np.where((df['col1']=='NT') & (df['lenghts']>max_skip),0,1)).ngroup()
df['cumsum_']=df.groupby(['group'])['group'].cumsum()
df['group']=np.where((df['group']==0),0,((df.cumsum_ != df.cumsum_.shift() + 1)).cumsum())
df['group']=df.groupby(['group']).ngroup()
df=df.drop(['lenghts','cumsum_'],axis=1)
print(df)
'''
   col1  group
0    NT      0
1    NT      0
2    NT      0
3     T      1
4     T      1
5     T      1
6    NT      1
7    NT      1
8     T      1
9     T      1
10    T      1
11   NT      0
12   NT      0
13   NT      0
14    T      2
15    T      2
16    T      2
17    T      2
18   NT      2
19   NT      2
```

Details:

```
#Let's take how many times each value in col1 is repeated.
df['lenghts'] = df.groupby(((df.col1 != df.col1.shift())).cumsum()).transform('size')
print(df)
'''
   col1  lenghts
0    NT        3
1    NT        3
2    NT        3
3     T        3
4     T        3
5     T        3
6    NT        2
7    NT        2
8     T        3
9     T        3
10    T        3
11   NT        3
12   NT        3
13   NT        3
14    T        4
15    T        4
16    T        4
17    T        4
18   NT        2
19   NT        2
'''

# now, write as 0 if col1 is NT and lenght is greater than "max_skip"
df['group']=df.groupby(np.where((df['col1']=='NT') & (df['lenghts']>max_skip),0,1)).ngroup() 

'''
   col1  lenghts  group
0    NT        3      0
1    NT        3      0
2    NT        3      0
3     T        3      1
4     T        3      1
5     T        3      1
6    NT        2      1
7    NT        2      1
8     T        3      1
9     T        3      1
10    T        3      1
11   NT        3      0
12   NT        3      0
13   NT        3      0
14    T        4      1
15    T        4      1
16    T        4      1
17    T        4      1
18   NT        2      1
19   NT        2      1
'''
#then we get the cumulative sum of the group column. If the group is 0, not 0, we define a new id with the code "df.cumsum_ != df.cumsum_.shift() + 1".

df['cumsum_']=df.groupby(['group'])['group'].cumsum()
df['group']=np.where((df['group']==0),0,((df.cumsum_ != df.cumsum_.shift() + 1)).cumsum())

'''
   col1  lenghts  group  cumsum_
0    NT        3      0        0
1    NT        3      0        0
2    NT        3      0        0
3     T        3      3        1
4     T        3      3        2
5     T        3      3        3
6    NT        2      3        4
7    NT        2      3        5
8     T        3      3        6
9     T        3      3        7
10    T        3      3        8
11   NT        3      0        0
12   NT        3      0        0
13   NT        3      0        0
14    T        4      7        9
15    T        4      7       10
16    T        4      7       11
17    T        4      7       12
18   NT        2      7       13
19   NT        2      7       14
'''
#It remains to define a new id according to the group column.
df['group']=df.groupby(['group']).ngroup()
```